# I keep receiving a .class expected error

Tags: java, arrays, methods, swap

Here is what I'm supposed to do:

> Write a program to read a 2-D array of 4x4. Then read the first element of the array and compare it with the third element of each column. Replace the smaller value with the larger values of the two. Create a method called swap to swap the values.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I'm just starting to learn arrays. My teacher is very conceptual and isn't very concrete on his definition so I'm having trouble with it. I keep receiving a .class expected error.

```
public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        int num [][] = {{4, 6, 7, 2},
                        {5, 12, 9, 8},
                        {1, 0, 3, 10},
                        {5, 3, 14, 11}};

        System.out.println("the array elements are:");
        for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
            System.out.println();
            for(int j = 0; j < num[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(num[i][j] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println("swaped elements are:");
        for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
            System.out.println();
            for(int j = 0; j < num[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(swap(num[][]) + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void swap (int x[][]){
        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            int temp = x[0][i];
            if (x[0][i] > x[2][i] ){
                x[2][i] = temp;
                x[0][i] = x[2][i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is ur problem? are u getting an error? if you'd paste some output it would help

Comment: This corresponds to the `someMethod(array[]);` example in the duplink

Answer (score 0):

`swap()` doesn't return anything.  Even if you did resolve the other issue (`num[][]` is a syntax error), you'd need to specify something to return from swap.  Hint:  probably the array you modified.

Comment: No. You can't bind another array to the passed object name, but changes you perform on the inside of the array will reflect in the original object. Java is `pass by copy of reference`, so the reference is copied, but it isn't a deep copy.

Comment: You're probably right - but if the OP wishes to _print_, then they would need to get some sort of _return value_.

Comment: guys I know what i did wrong, yeah i can't print the array value since swap doesnt return anything. what i did was just perform swap(num);

Comment: System.out.println();
  System.out.println("swaped elements are:");
  for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
   System.out.println();
   for(int j = 0; j < num[i].length; j++){
    swap(num);
    System.out.print(num[i][j] + " ");
   }

Comment: @p3ruviansoldi3r:  There's no real point to doing that inside of the loop (where you removed the `System.out.print`), since `swap` internally loops through the elements every time.  You'd be doing this swap `num.length * num[i].length` times.

Comment: @Makoto: No, if the user wants to print, he can just print after calling swap. It's the original array which gets resorted.

Comment: @p3ruviansoldi3r: Swap is an established name for changing two elements in a collection. Therefore I'm pretty sure your teacher expects a swap method which does just that: swap two elements. Comparing the elements should be done in a different method.

Answer (score 0):

- Write a program to read a 2-D array of 4x4.

I don't see you reading something. Just initializing it. Maybe you should read from stdin or from a file?

- Then read the first element of the array and compare it with the third element of each column.
- Replace the smaller value with the larger values of the two.
- Create a method called swap to swap the values

As a swap method I would expect a method with 4 indexes for the 2 positions in the 2D-Array, where the values to swap are located.

```
public static void swap (int x[][], int i1, int i2, int j1, int j2) {
    int temp  = x[i1][j1];
    x[i1][j1] = x[i2][j2];
    x[i2][j2] = temp;
}
```

Have you heard about the simplified for-loop?

```
public static void show (int x[][]) {
    for (int [] inner : x)
        for (int i : inner)
            System.out.print (i + " ");
}
```

Comment: No I don't know how to use a simplified for-loop i'll try to incorporate it on my code tho thanks :D!